# Getting value of AngularUI slider, and setting default/initial value of ng-bind

Tags: angularjs

I need to output the values and perform some calculations with the values of AngularUI sliders.

I have this mark-up:

```
<body ng-controller="sliderDemoCtrl">
            <div ui-slider="{range: 'min'}" min="0" max="50" ng-model="demoVals.slider"></div>
            <p>The value so far is:
              <span ng-bind="demoVals.slider"></span> // I want this to show 0 until the slider is moved
            </p>
            <p>The calculated value is: <input type="text" ng-model="calculated" value=" {{ calculated }}" placeholder=0 /></p>

</body>
```

Firstly, I can't work out how to initialise that `<span ng-bind="demoVals.slider"></span>` with a default value of 0 or "None". At the moment it is blank until the slider moves. How can I set this to a default value?

Secondly, I want the value of  `{{ calculated }}` to be a number multiplied by the value of the slider. How can I pass the value of the slider to `ng-model="calculated"` or access the value from within my controller?

[Here's my Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/zySArHvqZgJHHMq4DBL1?p=preview)

Answer (score 1):

You can set the initial value of the `ng-model` in the `$scope`:

```js
      $scope.demoVals = {};
      $scope.demoVals.slider = 0;
```

And to keep the value of `calculated` in one way `sync` with the `demoVals.slider`, you can use a `$watch` on the `$scope`:

```js
      $scope.$watch('demoVals.slider', function (newVal) {
        if (typeof newVal !== 'undefined') {
          $scope.calculated = newVal * 3.14159; // Use any value here.
        }
      });
```

[Working demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/dGbSTem5vtUoENPKf4jd?p=preview).

Answer (score 0):

The way `ng-model` works, it binds to the scope property you define in it's attribute value in the markup. If no such scope property exists, it gets created on initialization.

Thus, to set start value just create that model property. To adjust another scope property based on changes to the slider model you can use `$watch` to listen for changes to the slider model property

```
    app.controller('sliderDemoCtrl', function($scope) {
        /* ng-model bound to this object, so define it's start value*/
        $scope.demoVals={slider:10}
        /* watch for changes*/
        $scope.$watch('demoVals.slider',function(newVal,oldVal){
         if(newVal){
            $scope.calculated=2*newVal;
         }
      })

        $scope.calculated = 0;

    });
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/tZhQlxlGDSsah29wOWY7?p=preview)**</kbd>

Comment: The check in the `$watch` should read `if(typeof newVal !== 'undefined')` since '0' is a valid, but _falsey_ value for `newVal`. :)